# Search autocomplete for usernames: Is it better to query DB ONCE for all users, or query multiple times on each keystroke for 'users like'?

Tags: json, node.js, database, search, sequelize.js

I'm using a node/express backend, and angular on the front end. I have a feature where users can search for other users to add as a friend. My question is which method is less expensive. Let's, for the sake of argument, pretend there are 1 million user accounts.

1) When you enter the first keystroke in the user search field, a database query is done to find each users whose username begins with that letter, then the server responds with that entire json file, and you do a get request to that endpoint with your Angular front end. Every consecutively typed letter will no longer be doing a DB query, but will be utilizing that giant json array in the browser's memory and pulling up users as autocompleted suggestions.

or

2) Username's must be at least 6 characters long. Once you've entered 6 characters (significantly reducing the database query username possibilities), the db query is done, and the entire json file with usernames similar to that of your typed query is sent as a response. Every consecutive letter typed will filter for autocomplete from that point on.

OR

3) Same as number 2, however, instead of sending a single giant JSON object after 6 typed characters, each new consecutive letter typed will do a new, smaller db query, specifically targeted to find a DB entry with the exact string you have typed. Basically in angular an 'on change' listener. I.e Johnny will return an object with all usernames that start with Johnny, however, when I type Johnny1, now only the Johnny1 user object will get searched for as a DB query, then returned as the response if it exists. Then Johnny12 will do a DB query for the exact string (to lower case of course) for Johnny12... so on and so on.

Which of these methods is less expensive? Is it more expensive to do a SINGLE enormous DB query for the entire DB and send that over once and have that in front end memory? Or to do many small queries on each stroke, returning only a small fraction of the data, but allowing for more opportunities to possibly crash a server on the scale of 1 million users, each performing a request, each time they press a keystroke?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your database will be a driver for this answer. What DB are you using? If using a SQL database, make sure that `username` field is indexed. Whatever database, using the database structure to your best advantage will drive this answer more than the interface. A database like [elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) (available as an [AWS service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/)) would be (almost) real-time responses, so just do it every letter.

Your tree of possible responses will certainly shrink the more letters you include in the initial search. Getting to two or three initial letters before the first query would significantly help reduce the resulting payload.

Caching those initial search values could be handy as well. A caching DB (Redis, MemCache) would be nifty, but even just storing those results on your instance would help reduce latency of future queries coming through that instance (probably should expire them in some fashion or that cached data will become stale from the user DB, or each instance has to listen for added/removed users to update their chaches).

One last thought. Add some "debouncing" on your client side, such that you do not query every key stroke but give the user some time to finish typing. That will lighten the load on your DB, and reduce the amount of queries you have process on the client.

Comment: I am using a Postgres db. As it currently stands, I have more constraints on the client side...( #1) I am only doing the $http request once the typed in username is between 6 and 15 characters (usernames must validate to between 6 and 15 characters). (#2) Your debouncer suggestion is amazing. Before it was querying every keystroke change, now it only queries once after a 1000ms pause in typing. After every debouncer delay, the db queries for a username that matches and renders that user to the page. With the debouncer, I believe this is significant enough. Thank you ^

Comment: Great, glad that helped : )